# How to install Bun via homebrew formula

Tags: javascript, node.js, homebrew, bun

I want to install [Bun](https://bun.sh/) via homebrew but I cannot find a formula to install it.

Comment: Maybe there isn't one. https://github.com/Jarred-Sumner/bun/issues/272

Comment: looks like `Bun` isn't packaged for *any* package manager. They only provide a script that installs it, which they claim works on MacOS, Linux and WSL.

Comment: Bun is packaged in AUR (Arch User Repository). Check out bun-bin @Ester

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Before installing, you need to tap the repo:

```bash
brew tap oven-sh/bun
brew install bun
```

Comment: Still works with 1.0.

Answer (score 2):

Right now, bun is only in AUR according to [repology](https://repology.org/project/bun/versions). And you can search if it is there by `brew search bun`.

```
$ brew search "bun"
==> Formulae
bundler-completion          dylibbundler                libunistring                mecab-unidic                rbenv-bundler               run
bundletool                  jsonnet-bundler             libunwind                   mecab-unidic-extended       rbenv-bundler-ruby-version
cargo-bundle                libuninameslist             libunwind-headers           rbenv-bundle-exec           bup
```

[Update] I tried the provided installation steps, does not work for me with zig 0.10 (zig master build)

Comment: You need to use Jarred's custom zig fork on his GitHub.

Answer (score 1):

bun is not added in brew package bundle yet.

For now there is only one way install

```
curl https://bun.sh/install | bash
```